# Why can't custom comparator be used with hashSet to check duplicate objects

Tags: java, eclipse, hashset

I want to use a custom comparator to filter duplicate objects from a `HashSet`.

In the `Mobile` class, I have defined a non-static nested `Comparator` class for comparing. The criterium which is used by this comparator is the `id` field of the `Mobile` object.

```
Set<Mobile> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(new Mobile().new Comparator()); // works


Set<Mobile> hashSet = new HashSet<>(new Mobile().new Comparator()); // does not work
```

Even though it works perfectly for a `TreeSet`, Eclipse shows a syntax error when I try this with a `HashSet`,

It appears that I need to override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods in the `Mobile` class if I want to use a `HashSet`. However, I would prefer to use a comparator instead.

Why is this the case?

Comment: plz explain me...if you can help me with answer for my question Or I mean If I want to convert list to hashset , using custom duplicate criteria, whats the best way to do..

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do, do you want to store `Mobile` objects or `Comperator` objects in the set? If the first, implement your `hashcode` and `equals` in the `Mobile` class (you can use your `Comperator` implementation for `equals`). `HashSet` doesn't have a constructor which accepts a `Comperator` as the first argument, and it makes no sense either. `TreeSet` does, because it uses the comperator to order the objects (but `HashSet` is unordered)

Comment: Here's the java api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/.  `Comparator` is an interface, and can't be instantiated with just a `new` call (you must define the necessary functions).

Comment: @Teepeemm `Comparator` is the name of `Mobile` class's *inner class*.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Is there some documentation for `Mobile`?  It's not in the JDK, and searching for "Java Mobile api" doesn't give an api (not that I can recognize).

Comment: So OP is asking us to debug a class he wrote without giving us the source code?

Comment: @user323696, please add [all relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem in order to prevent your question from being closed by the community.

Comment: The guy really just wanted to know the difference between a HashSet and a TreeSet.  Then 3 people started nitpicking about syntax (which was irrelevant anyway) and closed his question because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet` is backed by a hashtable, which is an unordered data structure. This is why it has no need for a comparator. On the other hand, `TreeSet` is backed by a binary search tree (an ordered structure), and so it needs a comparator.

The correctness of a hashtable relies on the `equals` method, while its performance relies on a well-chosen `hashCode`. You can read more about it in the Javadoc of `HashSet` and the `Object.hashCode()` method itself.

Answer (score 2):

Hashset is designed not to accept duplicates !. So if your set does not contain given element it will add it to the set. If however in your set such element appears 2nd (same) element will not be added and will be discarded.

**HashSet:**

> class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, 
>   remove, contains and size). it does not guarantee that the order of
>   elements will remain constant over time iteration performance depends 
>   on the initial capacity and the load factor of the HashSet. It's
>   quite safe to accept default load factor but you may want to specify
>   an initial capacity that's about twice the size to which you expect
>   the set to grow.

**TreeSet:**

> guarantees log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and
>   contains) guarantees that elements of set will be sorted (ascending,
>   natural, or the one specified by you via it's constructor) doesn't
>   offer any tuning parameters for iteration performance offers a few
>   handy methods to deal with the ordered set like first(), last(),
>   headSet(), and tailSet() etc

**Important points:**

> Both guarantee duplicate-free collection of elements It is generally
>   faster to add elements to the HashSet and then convert the collection
>   to a TreeSet for a duplicate-free sorted traversal. None of these
>   implementation are synchronized. That is if multiple threads access a
>   set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it
>   must be synchronized externally. LinkedHashSet is in some sense
>   intermediate between HashSet and TreeSet. Implemented as a hash table
>   with a linked list running through it, however it provides
>   insertion-ordered iteration which is not same as sorted traversal
>   guaranteed by TreeSet.